# Color fading/wear cycling pants at seat bones/saddle contact points

Tags: wear, shorts

I invested in some proper cycling pants this year, Castelli Aero 4.0 bibshorts and Castelli Meno wind bibtights. This is only some months ago, but already the pants show signs of wear right under my seat bones. The color is not full black anymore but is turned white. Is this normal or is there something wrong with my saddle? I do also ride my bike in bad weather conditions, but always wash of the dirt when I come back.

Comment: What kind of saddle are you using? The material of the some saddles can be abrasive. Some saddles such as the [Brooks Cambium](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47226/how-to-prevent-brooks-cambium-c17-saddle-from-wearing-through-pants) are known to be abrasive.

Comment: This is happening to _both_ of them?  Can you check if they're getting thin?

Comment: Yes it is happening to both of them, I recently got a new bike so it could have been the old saddle. I now have a Giant Approach saddle. I doesn't look thinner, just color fading as far as I can tell

Comment: Castelli stuff is not cheap - Enquire about warranty.   I ride with $20 bibs and they last much longer than 3 months.

Comment: @Kibbee that's totally an answer, and probably right too.   A leather or plastic saddle surface will feel slippery to the touch and allow the cloth to slide without binding/catching, whereas a cloth saddle top can wear out clothes quickly.

Comment: In my experience, it’s normal for this to happen, but not so  quickly.

Answer (score 3):

This may or may not be your problem, but i've found a couple of things that can cause this issue.

1. Mountain biking in the wet wearing lycra: The saddle gets muddy/gritty and with the nature of riding off road causing a lot of changes in position and vibration, this acts as a grinding paste and does wear the material.  Dedicated MTB shorts have more robust materials in the seat area for this reason.  I assume the same is also true for gravel riding, or even regular riding in bad condtions on the road with no mudguards if done often enough.
2. Some brands of chamois cream.  I have a very thick long lasting cream (its more of a wax than a cream) that I use for very long rides.  I found this can migrate through the chamois and make the seat area a little discoloured.

Comment: I think you're right, after using mudguards ever since I found out,  I haven't seen it become worse.